# to_json converts DateTime from MongoDB to Python and back operation is not working

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I have a MongoDB with dates fields. I define the object like this one:

```
"
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d019fbdace49e498de7d915"),
    "created_date" : ISODate("2018-05-18T16:00:00.000Z"),
    "published_date" : ISODate("2018-05-18T16:00:00.000Z")
}
"
```

Mongoengine model looks like this one:

```
MyObject(Document):
    created_date = DateTimeField(default = datetime.datetime.utcnow)
```

When I get an object from database it comes to Python as:

```
'created_date':{'$date': 1463587200000}
```

I get objects doing to_json and back from_json. to_json() functions converts the Python datetime to this format. The problem is I don't know how to handle it back.

If I just try to save the object back (even if I don't touch this field, data is json)

```
doc = MyDoc(**data)
doc.save()
```

I have the following exception:

```
mongoengine.errors.ValidationError: ValidationError (MyObject:5d019aca1c9d4400008cb934) (cannot parse date "{'$date': 1463587200000}"
```

Answer (score 4):

`to_json()` doesn't help to handle this date conversion. The possible solution is to convert data using `to_mongo()` after retrieving from DB and after that convert it to Python-object using `to_dict()`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any problem using the data you mentioned.
I've inserted it in mongo with:

```
obj = {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d019fbdace49e498de7d915"),
    "created_date" : ISODate("2018-05-18T16:00:00.000Z"),
    "published_date" : ISODate("2018-05-18T16:00:00.000Z")
}
db.my_doc.insertOne(obj)
```

Then I'm able to read it, modify and save in mongoengine:

```
from  mongoengine import *
import datetime as dt

connect()

class MyDoc(Document):
    created_date = DateTimeField(default=dt.datetime.utcnow)
    published_date = DateTimeField(default=dt.datetime.utcnow)

doc = MyDoc.objects.first()
assert doc.created_date == dt.datetime(2018, 5, 18, 16, 0)
assert doc.published_date == dt.datetime(2018, 5, 18, 16, 0)

doc.created_date = dt.datetime.utcnow()
doc.save()
```

But if I insert the following:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d019fbdace49e498de7d916"),
    "created_date" : {
        "$date" : 1463587200000
    },
    "published_date" : ISODate("2018-05-18T16:00:00Z")
}
```

Then I get the ValidationError you mentioned. Mongoengine's DateTimeField correctly resolves to ISODate in mongodb, in this case it simply sounds like some of your documents have a different structure (or perhaps its your schema that should be changed). Double check the raw objects in mongodb and make sure they are all the same.

Comment: Thanks. How does datetime field look when you fetch it out from the database? My problem is the field looks good when I push it there but when I fetch it the mongoengine returns it in format as I described that can not be validated. And I don't know what to do with it.

Comment: datetime field is saved as an ISODate, do you observe a different behaviour. Could you simply create an instance with MyDoc().save() and open a mongo shell to check its raw format? Which version of mongo are you using?

Comment: in the title you mention, ‘to_json’, could you also clarify how you use it in this context?